# How to change one Boolean based on values found in ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop, boolean, sudoku

I am  trying to make a deductive Algorithm for solving a Sudoku puzzle. My Board is made up of 81 Nodes in an ArrayList. 
- Each Node has a boolean Value
I want my algorithm (called CRME) to be continue to try and solve the puzzle if it finds that at least one of the nodes has it's boolean value (hasChanged) equal to true but I am unsure how to do this. canChange is also a global variable in the class this method is contained in.

```
public void CRME() {
    canChange = true;
    while (canChange == true) {
        for (Node node : cells) {
            scanColumn(node);
            scanRow(node);
            scanMiniGrid(node);
        }
    }

}

    public void scanRow(Node n){
    for(Node node : cells){
        int arraySize = node.posVals.size();
        ArrayList<Integer> toRemove = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if(node.get_ROW_ID() == n.get_ROW_ID()){
            toRemove.add(node.getValue());
        } 
        n.posVals.removeAll(toRemove);
        if(arraySize < node.posVals.size()){
            node.hasChanged = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the scanRow method, the two other similarly named methods are the same but with the obvious syntax changed, such as node.get_ROW_ID(); would be node.get_COL_ID();.

Comment: Don't know what are you trying to achieve but I can see a possible infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a static variable

```
static boolean hasChanged; // in the Node class
```

so you can use:

```
 node.hasChanged = true;
```

or you can create hasChange method to set the variable like so

```
boolean hasChanged;

public void hasChanged(boolean val){
    this.hasChanged = val;
}
```

and use in the loop, like so:

```
hasChanged(true); or hasChanged(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not saying your approach is best, but if you are trying to simply continue while one of `hasChanged` is `true` for any of your nodes, the following will suffice:

```
public void CRME() 
{
    goOn = false;

    for (Node node : yourArrayListOfNodes) 
    {
        if (node.hasChanged)
        {
           goOn = true;
           break;
        }
    }

    if (goOn)
    {
        //Insert Whatever code you want to run after the check
        //.........................................

        //Use recursion to repeat process
        //Note recursive call will only take place if goOn is true
        CRME()
    } 
}
```

This seems like what you want to do, just note that if your logic is incorrect, you can get a `StackOverflowError`, since you would keep making recursive calls.